# what is the i and 0 doing here? can anybody explain?

Tags: javascript

I am taking the challenges from code-wars and I am looking at a solution and I don't understand it. Can somebody explain what `s` is doing as well as `o`?

```js
function duplicateEncode(word) {
  word = word.toLowerCase();
  var c = '', s = '', o = '';

  for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    s = word.slice(i + 1);
    o = s + word.slice(0, i);
    c += (o.indexOf(word[i]) > -1) ? ')' : '(';
  }

  return c;
}
```

Comment: the `i` is what place you are at in the var `word`, and the 0 tells `slice` to start at the beginning of the word and take until `i`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`String.prototype.slice` MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice#Parameters):

> ***beginIndex***
>
> The zero-based index at which to begin extraction. If
>   negative, it is treated as strLength + (beginIndex) where strLength is
>   the length of the string (for example, if beginIndex is -3 it is
>   treated as strLength - 3). If beginIndex is greater than or equal to
>   the length of the string, slice() returns an empty string.
>
> ***endIndex***
>
> Optional. The zero-based index before which to end extraction. The
>   character at this index will not be included. If endIndex is omitted,
>   slice() extracts to the end of the string. If negative, it is treated
>   as strLength + endIndex where strLength is the length of the string
>   (for example, if endIndex is -3 it is treated as strLength - 3).

Answer (score 1):

```
    s = word.slice(i + 1);
    o = s + word.slice(0, i);
```

these two lines get what's after the current character and what's before it and concatenate these two pieces. In other words, they build a string equal to the source string with the current char omitted. For example, if `word` is `abcde` and `i=2`, then `o` will be `de + ab = deab`. Of course, they could have simply written

```
    o = word.slice(0, i) + word.slice(i + 1)
```

with the same effect.

As a side note, this algorithm appears quite inefficient as it builds `word.length` temporary strings just to check the uniqueness. A more idiomatic approach would be to use `(last)indexOf` along the lines of

```
function duplicateEncode(word) {
    let w = [...word.toLowerCase()];
    return w
        .map(c => w.indexOf(c) === w.lastIndexOf(c) ? '(' : ')')
        .join('')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`s` will contain all the characters in `word` after the character at the current iteration

`o` will contain all the characters in `word` except the one at the current iteration (`s` + [all the characters in `word` from start till the one at the current iteration]).

This means that the `(o.indexOf(word[i]) > -1 )` expression will only be `true` if the character at the current iteration has a duplicate.